# Как экранировать данные в bash

Tags: bash, экранирование

```
#!/bin/bash
while true;
do
    myprogramm -r - "<<EOF
    comand1 path=/home/user/abc.uyz
    comand2

    sleep 60
    exit -y
    EOF"
sleep 3;
done;
```

Пробую вот так, при этом myprogram не видит команд.
Без цикла и экранирования работает как надо, как только добавляю цикл возникают трудности с чтением команд

Comment: Для более ли менне удобного программирования на shell есть такая библиотечка (она тоже на shell и переносима, в отличие от bash): http://git.altlinux.org/gears/l/libshell.git?p=libshell.git;a=summary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Две ошибки:

1. Кавычки не нужны
2. `EOF` в here-doc должен быть в начале строки, весь остальной документ желательно тоже должен быть без отступов (если не желаешь, чтобы эти отступы ушли не вход команде))

Т.е. правильным вариантом будет что-то вроде:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true;
do
    myprogramm -r - << EOF
comand1 path=/home/user/abc.uyz
comand2

sleep 60
exit -y
EOF

    sleep 3;
done;
```

Comment: важный момент забыл уточнить, в списке команд есть команды с путями в которых есть слеши

Comment: @user299447, не представляю, как это может на что-либо повлиять...

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно чтобы между EOF и EOF все данные шли как есть, без какой-либо специальной обработки, то это делается указанием ограничителя в кавычках. Например, возьмём такой [скрип для удобного получения сертификатов через certbot](https://www.alexeykopytko.com/2017/free-ssl-from-letsencrypt/#part-b9a9d4ff88603171):

```
tee /usr/local/bin/certbot-certonly <<'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
IFS=","
certbot certonly -d "$*";
EOF
```

В таком виде в файл `certbot-certonly` запишется всё как есть, без замены `$*` на, например, пустую строку.